# How many emergency/abnormal checklists are there for a typical airliner?

Tags: safety, airline-operations, checklist

(Related to, but hopefully not a dupe of, [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/21953/62))

The latest [NASA ASRS newsletter](http://asrs.arc.nasa.gov/publications/callback/cb_432.html) includes the case of an A320 crew that forgot to retract the gear and started detailed troubleshooting without noticing that the gear was still down. The captain said in his report that:

> I instructed the First Officer to coordinate landing at the divert
>   airport while I briefed the Lead Flight Attendant and then performed
>   the Airframe Vibration Checklist

The mention of an airframe vibration checklist caught my attention because it's such a specific scenario. So, excluding [normal operations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/21953/62), how many checklists does a typical airliner (like the A320) have for unusual/abnormal/emergency scenarios?

Answer (score 6):

> How many checklists does a typical airliner have for
>   unusual/abnormal/emergency scenarios?

Many. A book. The abnormal checklists usually compile to a book and it is located in the cockpit at all times.

As an example, there are 452 pages on the QRH of the Boeing 737. I counted **212** abnormal checklists using the index pages.

Answer (score 2):

You can [take a look here](http://www.737ng.co.uk/A320%20321%20FCTM%20Flight%20Crew%20Training%20Manual.pdf) to get a nice idea of some of the published ones (Im sure there are more, I'm still looking for a link to them). In general check lists exist for cases the manufactures may anticipate or unfortunately may have encountered in testing or operation. Some checklists may also stem from sub makers who built individual components like the engines or flight systems.